# jQuery .submit() not being called upon form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I simplified my code to reduce extraneous information, but I am having the same problem with the reduced code as with the more complex version. I have a form like this:

```
<form id="password_reset_form" action="script_reset_password.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Set Password" class="button-inactive" />
</form>
```

and jQuery code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#password_reset_form").submit(function(){
            alert("form submit attempted");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

But the jQuery `.submit()` is not being called. The goal is to prevent the form submission and display an error message if a particular condition is met, but my question is, why isn't `.submit()` being called when the `<input type="submit" />` is clicked?

Comment: Your submit function code is missing a closing `)`

Comment: Change `}` to `});` -- you must be seeing a syntax error. Dev tools are your friend, don't give them a cold shoulder. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to catch the `event` from within the callback function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#password_reset_form").submit(function(e){
        alert("form submit attempted");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: And close the event binding with a `);`.

Comment: Works fine without it for me (even though I agree that it belongs there). http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mpbtd4cz/

Comment: @j08691 nice to know that `event` is defined in the scope even if it *wasn't defined*...

Comment: @ DontVoteMeDown - Yeah but not in all browsers AFAIK for better support you must pass it in to the callback.

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax errors in your code, The document ready needs to be closed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#password_reset_form").submit(function(evt){
            alert("form submit attempted");
            evt.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h19bk8ft/2/